# android studio emulator : unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, instance, emulation

when running my app through the Android Virtual Machine, it crashes, returning me the following error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: en.company.client.name, PID: 4336
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity      
ComponentInfo{en.company.client.name/en.company.client.name.SplashScreen}:     
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     
"en.company.client.name.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file     
"/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file     
"/data/app/en.company.client.name-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/en.company.client.name-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"en.company.client.name.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file 
"/data/app/en.company.client.name-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/en.company.client.name-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

here's my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="en.company.client.name" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415">
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <permission android:name="en.company.client.name.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="en.company.client.name.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS" android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="name of app" android:theme="@style/Theme.Ab">
        <receiver android:name="en.company.client.name.SimpleWakefulReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="en.company.client.name.SimpleWakefulService"/>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4242000"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCpYsVH0zJSuL1SX5SuVoCP2RqeGqfSL1o"/>
    <meta-data android:name="bundleName" android:value="en.company.client"/>
    <meta-data android:name="displayName" android:value="name of app"/>
    <meta-data android:name="version" android:value="1.3"/>
    <meta-data android:name="build" android:value="3"/>
    <meta-data android:name="showroomName" android:value="name of app"/>
    <meta-data android:name="navBarCaption" android:value="name in navbar"/>
    <meta-data android:name="showroomAddr" android:value="address"/>
    <meta-data android:name="showroomPhone" android:value="phone number"/>
    <meta-data android:name="showroomMail" android:value="email"/>
    <meta-data android:name="showroomLatitude" android:value="latitude"/>
    <meta-data android:name="showroomLongitude" android:value="longitude"/>
    <meta-data android:name="assistanceForeignTel" android:value="international number"/>
    <meta-data android:name="assistanceNatTel" android:value="national number"/>
    <meta-data android:name="savPhone" android:value="service number"/>
    <meta-data android:name="savMail" android:value="service email"/>
    <meta-data android:name="isRent" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="mentionsAtelier" android:value="some legal mentions"/>
    <meta-data android:name="facebookLink" android:value="fb url"/>
    <meta-data android:name="mentions" android:value="more legal mentions"/>
    <activity android:label="name of app" android:name="en.company.client.name.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_news" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.News" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_news_web" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.NewsWeb" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_news" android:name="en.company.client.name.NewsPager" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_cars" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.Cars" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_cars" android:name="en.company.client.name.CarDetail" android:parentActivityName=".Cars" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="en.company.client.name.Gallery" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_staffs" android:name="en.company.client.name.StaffGridPager" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_cars" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.Showrooms" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:name="en.company.client.name.Maps" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about" android:label="@string/title_activity_staffs" android:name="en.company.client.name.StaffSimplePager" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="en.company.client.name.VideoPlayer" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:name="en.company.client.name.Widgets" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:name="en.company.client.name.White" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.Credits" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.Assistance" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.Atelier" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="en.company.client.name.Rent" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:name="en.company.client.name.AtelierSuccess" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    <activity android:name="en.company.client.name.PackAssurance" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Android Studio underlines two errors in AndroidManifest.xml :

on platformBuildVersionCode="23" and on platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415"

both stating "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

I do not know if the errors are related but, probably not good anyway..

This project is not built with gradle, and I do not know how to add gradle to it.

Comment: did u correctly mentioned `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     
"en.company.client.name.SplashScreen"`, seems the class is not found

Comment: well this isn't originally my project, we're trying to update the app, Android(and iOS, but managed to get this done) isn't my original area of expertise, I will look up, but would you have any idea where it should be declared ?

Comment: Please add Activity SplashScreen in AndroidManifest.xml       <activity android:name="en.company.client.name.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that your identifiers `platformBuildVersionCode` and  `platformBuildVersionName` are a missing a namespace. All XML-Identifiers have a namespace followed by the key, like `android:name`

Futhermore the keys are not valid identifiers for the build version and name, it is

```
 android:versionCode="integer"
 android:versionName="string"
```

like mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

To add Gradle to your project you can import the project in Android Studio.

And your error is caused by a missing class. You should check your XML-Layout (not the manifest) and compare the class-identifier with the class in your code.

Comment: Thank you for sending me to the right direction ! Found all my .class and .java files(including Splashcreen and more, but as Splashcreen really is what comes first in the app, guess it has only times to return this problem) are not tied to the project. However, I do not know how to properly add them back

Answer (score 0):

In your pc.

> Goto your project folder delete the Project> `build` folder &
>
> Project> src > `build` folder. Then rebuild your project.Project